# How to POST multiple HTML5 form data to a single REST Service?

Tags: javascript, java, html, rest, post

I have a HTML5 page that has two forms on it, posting to the same REST service:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="formOne" action="/v1/info">
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <form id="formTwo" action="/v1/info">
        <input type="text" name="someOtherInfo"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


@Path("/v1/info")
@Component
public class V1Services {    

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public static Response storeInfo(
        @Context HttpServletResponse response,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("someOtherInfo") String someOtherInfo,
        ...
}
```

I'd like to send the data from both forms when the user submits either of them.  Combining the two forms in to a single one would involve a lot of work redesigning the layout of the site, which I would prefer to do later.

Is it possible to submit the data from both forms to the REST service without combining them in to a single HTML5 form?

Comment: yes, just use ajax to submit the form and merge the two data object into one before submitting.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?